# How to change the content of JS Popover inside ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to change the content inside the pop-up box , that is created using bootstrap popover plugin[data-popover] on ajax success.

On page load , the popover content of an element is set default inside "title" attribute.
But my challenge here is "to change the popover content in success response of an ajax call " ,
Ajax call is initiated on click event of an element

On page load , the popover content of an element is set default inside "title" attribute.

```html
<span class=" priority " id="p_over" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" title="<center>Priority </center>" target="_blank"></span>
```

On click enent:

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.priority', function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: myurl
        data: mydata
        success: function (data) {

            $("#p_over").removeClass("priority");
            $("#p_over").addClass("normal");
            if($('.popover').hasClass('in')){
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).attr('title','Cannot proceed with Save while Editing a row.');
                $(this).popover('show');
            } 

        }
    }); 
});
```

I expect the content change inside the popover in ajax success of of onclick event of a span element

Comment: Try `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: span have no class `popover`  when you check if condition.

Comment: Also `this`  is not work inside if condition. You need to give proper class / id .

Comment: Now I changed the code as follows , but also the popover does not occur .<span class=" priority " id="p_over" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-title="<center>Priority </center>" target="_blank"></span>
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: myurl
        data: mydata
        success: function (data) {

            $("#p_over").removeClass("priority");
            $("#p_over").addClass("normal");
            $("#p_over").attr("data-title","normal");

        }
    });

Comment: $(this).attr('data-original-title','aaaa');  gives me the solution